# question about a derivation of an inequality [ related to wieners attack in cryptography ]

Tags: inequality, cryptography

I had a question
regarding a formula derivation from a cryptography class
I am taking.  Not really a crypto question.. Just more wondering how
does one go from LHS to RHS in above equality ?

$d<=(N^.25)/3  => (\frac{1}{2d^2} )  - (\frac{1}{N^.5} ) >=  (\frac{3}{N^.5} )  $
[Implication-1]

I have attached  a screenshot from where the lecturer
mentions the above equivalence.  He seems to be skipping
some steps.. so to complete my understanding, I filled them in...like this ->>>

square both sides, then invert   (flipping inequality direction):
$d<=(N^.25)/3    \implies (\frac{1}{d ^2} )  >= (\frac{9}{N^.5} )$

multiply both sides by 1/3:
$ (\frac{1}{3} ) * (\frac{1}{d ^2} )  >=   (\frac{1}{3} ) * (\frac{9}{N^.5} ) $

and we obtain this ->

$ (\frac{1}{3*d ^2} )  >=   (\frac{3}{N^.5} ) $

Note that the RHS is same as RHS in  [Implication-1]
But the LHS -- which in the above is
$(\frac{1}{3*d ^2} ) $
-- does not equal
the original in [Implication-1] -- which is
$(\frac{1}{2d} )^2  - (\frac{1}{N^.5} ) $

Thanks in advance for any guidance/tips/etc !

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See your screenshot to notice a horrendous misspelling in your title of the name of a famous mathematician.

Comment: Square $\frac1d\ge\frac 3{N^{1/4}}$ to get $
\textstyle\frac1{2d^2}\ge \frac9{2N^{1/2}}\ge \frac4{N^{1/2}}=\frac3{N^{1/2}}+\frac1{N^{1/2}}\,.
$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  And I sincerely apologize if the misspelling upset you or offended you in any way. That was not my intention.

Comment: It offends the friends and family of Norbert W$\color{red}{ie}$ner, not me. Please fix it. At MSE we have some standards.

Comment: Sure thing ;^)    fixed

Comment: @KurtG. Even though the family of Michael J. Wiener is the offended party.

Comment: @kimchilover [Right!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_attack) Thanks for poining that out. No Arnold principle here by which a theorem that is named after a person is due to someone living earlier.